# Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath' android studio

Tags: java, android, gradle

I'm new to Android development with Java. I made an app that allows you to log in with Google and Facebook. Everything worked fine until about three days ago when the following message appeared:

> org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException:
> Could not resolve all files for configuration
> ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.

I tried updating Gradle, but it didn't work. I leave you my configuration so that you can help me.

build.gradle(module):

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'

}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 32
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.wuad"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    namespace 'com.example.wuad'
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
    implementation files('libs\\twitter4j-core-4.0.7.jar')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:23.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:19.0.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:latest.release'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.12.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.9.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:last.release'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:[8,9)'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'
    implementation "androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0"
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-core:latest.release'

}
```

build.gradle(project):

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.0'
        

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

the error message and the stack trace

```
2022-05-14 17:46:48.012 532-566/? E/KernelCpuSpeedReader: Failed to read cpu-freq: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/stats/time_in_state: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
2022-05-14 17:46:48.013 532-566/? E/KernelCpuSpeedReader: Failed to read cpu-freq: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/stats/time_in_state: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
2022-05-14 17:46:48.032 205-209/? E/android.system.suspend@1.0-service: Error opening kernel wakelock stats for: wakeup34: Permission denied

2022-05-14 17:48:08.977 473-473/? E/netmgr: qemu_pipe_open_ns:62: Could not connect to the 'pipe:qemud:network' service: Invalid argument
2022-05-14 17:48:08.977 473-473/? E/netmgr: Failed to open QEMU pipe 'qemud:network': Invalid argument
2022-05-14 17:48:09.384 477-477/? E/wifi_forwarder: qemu_pipe_open_ns:62: Could not connect to the 'pipe:qemud:wififorward' service: Invalid argument
2022-05-14 17:48:09.384 477-477/? E/wifi_forwarder: RemoteConnection failed to initialize: RemoteConnection failed to open pipe
2022-05-14 17:48:55.785 205-209/? E/android.system.suspend@1.0-service: Error opening kernel wakelock stats for: wakeup34: Permission denied
2022-05-14 17:48:55.790 205-209/? E/android.system.suspend@1.0-service: Error opening kernel wakelock stats for: wakeup35: Permission denied

2022-05-14 18:06:06.530 532-566/? E/KernelCpuSpeedReader: Failed to read cpu-freq: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/stats/time_in_state: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
2022-05-14 18:06:06.530 532-566/? E/KernelCpuSpeedReader: Failed to read cpu-freq: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/stats/time_in_state: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
2022-05-14 18:06:06.585 205-209/? E/android.system.suspend@1.0-service: Error opening kernel wakelock stats for: wakeup34: Permission denied
2022-05-14 18:06:06.591 205-209/? E/android.system.suspend@1.0-service: Error opening kernel wakelock stats for: wakeup35: Permission denied

2022-05-14 18:06:10.138 5909-5987/? E/GEL_DELAYED_EVENT_DEBUG: Failed delayed event dispatch, no dispatchers.
2022-05-14 18:06:10.437 5909-5988/? E/AwarenessClientProvider: Account associated with identity was null
2022-05-14 18:06:10.487 5909-5986/? E/AwarenessRouterSyncMgr: Exception while syncing fences
    java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Account associated with identity was null
        at zsp.a(PG:135)
        at zsp.get(PG:82)
        at zwj.a(PG:1)
        at zuv.a(PG:4)
        at fyf.run(Unknown Source:1)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:462)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at pqt.run(PG:13)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Account associated with identity was null
        at fxj.a(Unknown Source:3)
        at zsr.a(PG:3)
        at zst.run(PG:23)
        at zvn.run(PG:2)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:462) 
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
        at pqt.run(PG:13) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
```

Comment: The gradle error message usually contains the hint that you should call gradle with `--stacktrace` have you done that? Please edit your question and include the error message and the stack trace you get by doing so.

Comment: @Robert I just added what was requested in your comment. Regards

Comment: Replace `jcenter()` with `mavenCentral()` and Java `VERSION_1_8` with `VERSION_11`. That stacktrace is completely unrelated, as for a `buld.gradle`, only the Gradle log is relevant.

Answer (score 0):

no that means you/smthn (can be an update) changed your dependencies, you should reArrange them.

it has an example here: [Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'. while adding new dependencies in android studio chipmunk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73201592/could-not-resolve-all-files-for-configuration-appdebugruntimeclasspath-whil)