How can i solve "Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'"
When I tried to run the java mobile app for the first time, I started to receive the following error. I researched a lot on the internet, but none of the alternatives were a solution. How can I solve this?
Error:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find androidx.multidex:multidex:2.1.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/multidex/multidex/2.1.0/multidex-2.1.0.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/androidx/multidex/multidex/2.1.0/multidex-2.1.0.pom
       - https://jitpack.io/androidx/multidex/multidex/2.1.0/multidex-2.1.0.pom
     Required by:
         project :app

build.gradle:
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.smartup.rentcasedemo'
    compileSdkVersion 31
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.smartup.rentcasedemo"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.1.0' // Güncellenmiş multidex kütüphanesi
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.7.7'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.7.7'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
}


Edit: I think the error is caused by multiDexEnabled import. If I do not import multiDexEnabled I get the following error.
Caused by: org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkExecutionException: A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction


Edit: I solved the problem with the solution below.
Duplicate class in Kotlin Android

It looks like you've only shared part of the error message there. Please share the full one to increase the chance of the answer being right!

I hope this will fix your issue.
https://stackoverflow.com/q/73201592/7874746

@SimonJacobs i was edited post.

@AbdullahJaved I have reviewed this before. It didn't work.

You're trying to use version 2.1.0 of multidex when the latest is 2.0.1 (Google repo).
You need to replace the line:
implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.1.0'

with:
implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'

